# shadowsocks or l2tp which more fast and stable

Tags: vpn, tunnel, l2tp

some game is Censorship in iran we most tunnel the internet between my device and vps in Foreign country

but now want to know which protocol is fast shadowsocks or l2tp ?

Answer (score 0):

l2tp uses udp, shadowsocks uses tcp, I think l2tp is faster. Maybe you can test both in your network.